# Is there any replacement for vmax in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using vmax for height and width.

It works perfectly fine in firefox and chrome and It is responsive.

But in IE, it is not working.

Is there any replacement for vmax which i can use in IE too?

It should be responsive?

Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: https://github.com/rodneyrehm/viewport-units-buggyfill

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vmax units can be easily substituted with the use of CSS `calc()`.

`<scalar>vmax: calc(<scalar> * (1vw + 1vh - 1vmin));`

Replace `<scalar>` with your desired vmax value. This currently works in the most used versions of IE because vmin does have support, though none of the viewport width units are supported in IE8 and below.

You can read more about this solution [here](https://codepen.io/TBernard/post/using-vmax-units-in-ie).